STM32H7 CortexM4 DMA issue
I'm trying to use USART  + RTS only + DMA(non circular, peripheral to memory, DMA1 Stram0) on STM32H755ZIT6's M4 processor.
I and D caches are enabled.
My code is working on M7 but it does not works on M4 and I'm getting Framing Error , which means that the stop bit is not recognized on reception at the expected time
// u8* dma_rx_buffer_ = (u8*)((u32)0x24000000);
// u8* dma_rx_buffer_ = (u8*)((u32)0x38000000);
u8* dma_rx_buffer_ = (u8*)((u32)0x30000000);

int main(void)
{
    //SCB_InvalidateDCache_by_Addr((u32*)dma_rx_buffer_, 14);
    error = HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&usart2_dma_, dma_rx_buffer_, 14);
}

as you can see I'm setting RAM_D2's address to the dma_rx_buffer_, but I can't use SCB_InvalidateDCache_by_Addr on M4.
This is M7's Flash.ld
MEMORY {   
         RAM_D1 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x24000000, LENGTH =  512K
         FLASH   (rx)   : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
         DTCMRAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
         RAM_D2 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 288K
         RAM_D3 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x38000000, LENGTH = 64K
         ITCMRAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 64K
      }

this is M4's Flash.ld
MEMORY
    {
       FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x08100000, LENGTH = 1024K
       RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 288K
       //RAM_D2 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 288K
       //RAM_D3 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x38000000, LENGTH = 64K
    }

I also tried to add RAM_D1 and RAM_D2 inside M4's Flash.ld file and use it like this
`attribute ((section(".RAM_D2"))) attribute ((aligned (32))) u8* dma_rx_buffer_;
but no result.
I also read DMA is not working on STM32H7 devices, but can't find solution.
P.S all configurations, including DMA are correct .
Also when I'm setting different addresses for dma_rx_buffer_ then I'm getting different data.
Do I need to add MPU region for CortexM4?
Update: Configured MPU region accrding DRAM addresses, but no result, with RAM_D1, RAM_D2 or RAM_D3.
/* Disable fault exceptions */
SCB->SHCSR &= ~SCB_SHCSR_MEMFAULTENA_Msk;

/* Disable the MPU and clear the control register*/
MPU->CTRL = 0;

MPU->CTRL = MPU_PRIVILEGED_DEFAULT | MPU_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;

SCB->SHCSR |= SCB_SHCSR_MEMFAULTENA_Msk;

__DSB();
__ISB();

MPU->RNR = MPU_REGION_NUMBER8;

//MPU->RBAR = 0x24000000;
//MPU->RBAR = 0x38000000;
MPU->RBAR = 0x30000000;
MPU->RASR = ((uint32_t)MPU_INSTRUCTION_ACCESS_ENABLE << MPU_RASR_XN_Pos)   |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_REGION_FULL_ACCESS << MPU_RASR_AP_Pos)   |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_TEX_LEVEL0 << MPU_RASR_TEX_Pos)  |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_ACCESS_SHAREABLE << MPU_RASR_S_Pos)    |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_ACCESS_CACHEABLE << MPU_RASR_C_Pos)    |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_ACCESS_BUFFERABLE << MPU_RASR_B_Pos)    |
            ((uint32_t)0x00 << MPU_RASR_SRD_Pos)  |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_REGION_SIZE_32B << MPU_RASR_SIZE_Pos) |
            ((uint32_t)MPU_REGION_ENABLE << MPU_RASR_ENABLE_Pos);

